# smartgrid validation on non-writable field

Tags: web2py

I have two linked tables (car_make,car_model).

```
db.define_table('car_make',
            Field('id', type='id', notnull=True),
            Field('name',type='string', notnull=True, unique=True),
            format='%(name)s'
           )
db.define_table('car_model',
            Field('id',type='id', notnull=True),
            Field('company', 'reference car_make', notnull=True),
            Field('name',type='string', notnull=True),
            Field('mfr_year',type='integer', notnull=True)
           )
```

I am using the IS_NOT_IN_DB validator to ensure that car_model records are unique based on car_make/name/mfr_year.

```
db.car_model.name.requires=IS_NOT_IN_DB(db((db.car_model.company==request.vars.company) & (db.car_model.mfr_year==request.vars.mfr_year)),'car_model.name')
```

Before I create the smartgrid I set

```
db.car_model.company.writable=False
```

1. So that the smartgrid will display the formatted value for the selected car_make.
2. Since the user selected the car_make record they shouldn't need to update it.

Unfortunately, it appears that setting the writable property to False breaks the IS_NOT_IN_DB() validation, because the field doesn't get included in the form and as a result request.vars.company doesn't get set.

Is there a way to use smartgrid with the non-writable field and still enforce the multi-field uniqueness using smartgrid?

Here is my code for the smartgrid

```
grid = SQLFORM.smartgrid(db.car_make,
                     linked_tables=['car_model'],
                     create=dict(car_make=True, 
                                 car_model=True),
                     deletable=dict(car_make=True, 
                                    car_model=True),
                     editable=dict(car_make=True, 
                                   car_model=True),
                     advanced_search=False,
                     searchable=dict(car_make=True, car_model=False),
                     details=False,
                     csv=False,
                     maxtextlength=100
                     )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the ID of the `car_model` record from the URL and use that to get the associated `car_make` ID in order to construct the query for the `IS_NOT_IN_DB` validator:

```
if request.args(-2) == 'car_model' and request.args(-1).isdigit():
    car_model = db.car_model(request.args(-1))
    same_company = db.car_model.company == car_model.company
    same_year = db.car_model.mfr_year == request.vars.mfr_year
    query = same_company & same_year
    db.car_model.name.requires = IS_NOT_IN_DB(db(query), 'car_model.name')
```

Note, you can also get the `car_model.company` value directly from the URL via `request.args(-4)`, which is a little less straightforward but does not require fetching the `car_model` record from the database.

Comment: This appears works as long as the validator is added to a field that is writable.

Comment: Yes. You shouldn't need a validator on a non-writable field.